# Speedup disk array search

Tags: arrays, tree, disk, b-tree

I have very large immutable array stored in disk file.

It is binary file and all records are same size, so I can seek and access any record directly. This is oversimplification, but is good example:

```
struct Record{
   char key[8];
   char value[16];
   uint16_t some_data;
   // ...
} __attribute__((__packed__));
```

In order to find an element, currently I am doing binary search there, but for large arrays, it takes 20 or more lookups, e.g. disk seeks.

Is there any easy and clean way I can speedup this find_element function, by creating some additional index file or something?

I thought about BTrees / B+Trees, but I am unsure how easily to convert the array to BTree.

I also thought for level-ordered array, but I am unsure if it will have such a big effect, even first several lookups will be very "close" each to other.

> This "normal" array:
>
> 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7
>
> Will look level ordered like this:
>
> 4, 2, 6, 1, 3, 5, 7

I am using C++.

Comment: Is it a text file? Is the array already sorted (I suppose this because you talk about binary search)? Can you provide an example for that file? How big is it in bytes?

Comment: no, binary file, with fixed size records, contain key for searching

Comment: your find function, it returns the index of the found value or the value given an index?

Comment: it returns the data, but internally I need the position.

Comment: if you are not searching for partial matches, your array isn't sorted and your queries are whole perfect matches of the value, you could store in a separate file the first 1-2 bytes of each value, syncronized line-by-line with the original file's entries. your find function parses entirely this file (which is alot smaller and thus loadeable in ram entirely or in chuncks) and implicitely narrow the entries that start with said bytes of your query. Alternatively, sort your array by value and create another file with the positions of the first entries whose value starts with a particular octet.

Comment: to be honest, the key is not 8 bytes, but much longer - could go to 4 KB. Also it is possible most or all keys to have common 5-6 byte prefix as well, e.g. "user_005", "user_120" etc.

Comment: @Nick hold on can you guarantee that the total size in bytes of every entry is always the same even if the key can change so drastically?

Comment: real answer is more complicated, but for simplicity, let suppose key and value are zero padded.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120547/discussion-between-user2464424-and-nick).

Comment: You've already given some info on the keys (variable, up to 4KB) but it is also important to know what you mean by 'large'. Millions of records? Billions? Be as precise as possible. And how 'immutable' is the data? Daily rebuild? Monthly? Never? If you don't need prefix/range queries then you should definitely consider hashing; also, have a peek at [tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) and [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort) for inspiration.

Comment: billions :) I already implemented BTree there, but still making improvements, so I did not answer my question yet.